# How to get out from onClick method for Button Listener in Android

Tags: android, onclicklistener

COnsider this following code:

```
Button add_product_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_product_button);
    add_product_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //Before going further, we check whether all the information is provided or not
            EditText item_title_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.item_title);
            if(isEmpty(item_title_text)){
                break;
            }
```

I want the 'break;' to be the response that I would not want to proceed further (not executing the rest code and just get out).

This is to alarm user that insufficient information has been provided. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would actually recommend ***disabling*** your button if the required information is not there so the user isn't able to click it. You could display a message on whatever dialog/view to inform the user that information is required, or add a string like "(required)" after the EditText hint.

```
Button add_product_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_product_button);
EditText item_title_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.item_title);

if(isEmpty(item_title_text)){
    add_product_button.setEnabled(false);
}
```

***However***, if you need to do it the way you described for some reason, to answer how you "get out", you just need to `return` out of the onClick method.

```
if(isEmpty(item_title_text)){
    return;
}
```

Before returning you could call some method that does whatever you want to do (your own method that perhaps displays a message to the user that they have not enough information).

```
if(isEmpty(item_title_text)){
    notifyUserOfEmptyField();
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get out of it without going on with the code just

```
if(isEmpty(item_title_text)){
    return;
}
```

You might want to show a Toast with the error in there:

```
if(isEmpty(item_title_text)){
    Toast.makeText(...);
    return;
}
```